# How to pass extra parameter with JQuery Dropzone to my java controller method

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, dropzone

I have a dropzone function to upload pdf files and receive it in my controller method to process and save in database, but i need to pass an extra parameter which is the value from a select, i already pass it but i receive "null" value in controller method.

this is mi JQuery dropzone method:

```
 ...
 $("div#uploadFile").dropzone({ 
                        
     url: "/demo/uploadFile"
     ,params: {
               name: $( "#selectedName" ).val()
              }
    ,acceptedFiles: ".pdf"
    ,clickable: false
    ,maxFilesize: 100
    ,addRemoveLinks: true
    ,init: function() {
                         
              this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                         //i can see the value in alert
                         alert($( "#selectedName" ).val()); 
              });
              this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                         alert("ok");
              });
               
  });
```

the controller method (trying to receive in requestParam):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile( @RequestParam("name") String name, MultipartFile file)  {

          //here print parameter and is  NULL
          System.out.println("My extra param received is : "+ name);
         
         //process the file-pdf
          ...
          ....

}
```

Any idea?  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
 $("div#uploadFile").dropzone({ 
                        
     url: "/demo/uploadFile"
    ,acceptedFiles: ".pdf"
    ,clickable: false
    ,maxFilesize: 100
    ,addRemoveLinks: true
    ,init: function() {
                         
              this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                         //i can see the value in alert
                         alert($( "#selectedName" ).val()); 
              });
              this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
                        formData.append("name", $( "#selectedName" ).val());
                        console.log(formData);
              });
              this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                         alert("ok");
              });
               
  });
```

Comment: it works! this way is not necessary params in dopzone function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any file to byte array on JS side and decode it in java side, so you can send byte array instead of file. Use something like this on your JS side (You should add promises to this JS method):

```
function getBufferArray(file) {
   var fr = new FileReader();
   fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
   return new Uint8Array(fr.result);
}
```

And on your java side:

```
public class BASE64DecodedMultipartFile implements MultipartFile {
        private final byte[] imgContent;

        public BASE64DecodedMultipartFile(byte[] imgContent) {
            this.imgContent = imgContent;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            // TODO - implementation depends on your requirements 
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getOriginalFilename() {
            // TODO - implementation depends on your requirements
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            // TODO - implementation depends on your requirements
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return imgContent == null || imgContent.length == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getSize() {
            return imgContent.length;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
            return imgContent;
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(imgContent);
        }

        @Override
        public void transferTo(File dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException { 
            new FileOutputStream(dest).write(imgContent);
        }
    }
```

For pharameters try adding to your dropzone:

```
        params: {
            new_value: 'value'
        },
```

Comment: ok but this is not the problem, i already process de file and save it well, just need to pass a parameter that is not part of the file, i get the parameter from a select box

Comment: Updated it, you can do it without dropzone by converting your file to byte array as I said and sending it with regular ajax POST request in data{} or try adding params: {}.

Comment: updated mi post, i add the parameter in dropzone as you say  and it works, but i received null value, however i alert that in dropzone.addedFile function and i can see the value.

Comment: Use `$("checkbox/select element").is(':selected');`

Comment: not work, i already use that before dropzone function and pass nameValue in params and still print null:
                                      var nameValue;
                                      $('#selectedName').on('change', function(){
                                          nameValue=$( "#selectedName" ).val();
                                      });